# How do I insert test data in Play Framework 2.0 (Scala)?

Tags: unit-testing, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm having some problems with making my tests insert fake data in my database. I've tried a few approaches, without luck. It seems that Global.onStart is not run when running tests within a FakeApplication, although I think I read that it should work.

```
object TestGlobal extends GlobalSettings {
  val config = Map("global" -> "controllers.TestGlobal")

  override def onStart(app: play.api.Application) = {
    // load the data ... 
  }
}
```

And in my test code:

```
private def fakeApp = FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = (
  inMemoryDatabase().toSeq +
  TestGlobal.config.toSeq
).toMap, additionalPlugins = Seq("plugin.InsertTestDataPlugin"))
```

Then I use `running(fakeApp)` within each test.

The `plugin.InsertTestDataPlugin` was another attempt, but it didn't work without defining the plugin in `conf/play.plugins` -- and that is not wanted, as I only want this code in the test scope.

Should any of these work? Have anyone succeeded with similar options?

Comment: Did you spell ```InsertTestDataPlugin``` correctly? Because a Google search only brought up this SO question.

Comment: Yeah, I made the plugin myself, by extending the Plugin-class :-) It worked when used in the main source, and added in play.plugins. It has an onStart method. But that had to be in the main source scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chose to solve this in another way:

I made a fixture like this:

```
def runWithTestDatabase[T](block: => T) {
  val fakeApp = FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = inMemoryDatabase())

  running(fakeApp) {
    ProjectRepositoryFake.insertTestDataIfEmpty()
    block
  }
}
```

And then, instead of `running(FakeApplication()){ /* ... */}`, I do this:

```
class StuffTest extends FunSpec with ShouldMatchers with CommonFixtures {
  describe("Stuff") {
    it("should be found in the database") {
      runWithTestDatabase {       // <--- *The interesting part of this example*
        findStuff("bar").size must be(1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Global.onStart should be executed ONCE (and only once) when the application is launched, whatever mode (dev, prod, test) it is in. Try to follow [the wiki on how to use Global](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/ScalaGlobal).

In that method then you can check the DB status and populate. For example in Test if you use an in-memory db it should be empty so do something akin to:

```
if(User.findAll.isEmpty) {  //code taken from Play 2.0 samples

      Seq(
        User("guillaume@sample.com", "Guillaume Bort", "secret"),
        User("maxime@sample.com", "Maxime Dantec", "secret"),
        User("sadek@sample.com", "Sadek Drobi", "secret"),
        User("erwan@sample.com", "Erwan Loisant", "secret")
      ).foreach(User.create)   

  }
```

Comment: Does that mean that running(FakeApplication("global"->"path.to.my.Global")) has no effect within a test?

Comment: @Arve I'm not sure, but I'm sure the other way works, as you can see in the scala samples (zen project)

Comment: Seems Global was not the place to do this, especially if you want different database contents for different tests. See how I solved it in my own answer.